# Как реализовать перелистывание сообщения в aiogram с помощью inline кнопок?

Tags: python, aiogram

Пишу телеграм бота и столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу найти информацию, как как реализовать перелистывание сообщения в aiogram с помощью inline кнопок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выглядеть это должно примерно так. Мне нужно чтобы с помощью этих кнопок можно было перелистывать очень длинное сообщение, так как в телеграмме есть ограничение на длину сообщения. Буду рад любой помощи

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Ну к примеру вот так.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

from data import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="prev")
async def prev_page(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    data = int(call.data.split(":")[1]) - 1

    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        InlineKeyboardButton("PREV", callback_data=f"prev:{data}"),
        InlineKeyboardButton(str(data), callback_data="null"),
        InlineKeyboardButton("NEXT", callback_data=f"next:{data}"),
    )
    await call.message.edit_text("text", reply_markup=markup)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="next")
async def next_page(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    data = int(call.data.split(":")[1]) + 1

    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        InlineKeyboardButton("PREV", callback_data=f"prev:{data}"),
        InlineKeyboardButton(str(data), callback_data="null"),
        InlineKeyboardButton("NEXT", callback_data=f"next:{data}"),
    )
    await call.message.edit_text("text", reply_markup=markup)


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def handler(msg: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        InlineKeyboardButton("PREV", callback_data=f"prev:0"),
        InlineKeyboardButton("0", callback_data="null"),
        InlineKeyboardButton("NEXT", callback_data=f"next:1")
    )
    await msg.answer('text', reply_markup=markup)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```